# WebElement and drive.driver little tricky

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to understand what would it be the right thing to do in here and i do not fully understand it.

Take a look:

```java
String <WebElement> a = drive.driver.getTitle(By.xpath("somelocator"));
List <WebElement> a = drive.driver.findElement(By.xpath("somelocator"));
Boolean <WebElement> a = drive.driver.switchTO(By.xpath("somelocator"));
Map <WebElement> a = drive.driver.quit(By.xpath("somelocator"));
List <WebElement> a = drive.driver.findElements(By.xpath("somelocator"));
```

What would it be the right thing to do? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only 2 legal expressions here are

```java
List <WebElement> a = drive.driver.findElement(By.xpath("somelocator"));
List <WebElement> a = drive.driver.findElements(By.xpath("somelocator"));
```

While only 1 expression here is making sense

```java
List <WebElement> a = drive.driver.findElements(By.xpath("somelocator"));
```

Because this expression:

```java
drive.driver.findElements(By.xpath("somelocator"));
```

Returns a *List* of `WebElement` objects that will match what you defined on the left side `List <WebElement> a`
While this:

```java
drive.driver.getTitle(By.xpath("somelocator"));
```

returns a  single `WebElement` object instance so assigning a single object to a list

```java
List <WebElement> a = drive.driver.findElement(By.xpath("somelocator"));
```

Will work, but will not really make sense.
Instead of that you should use something like

```java
WebElement a = drive.driver.findElement(By.xpath("somelocator"));
```

While
`String <WebElement>` or `Boolean <WebElement> a` or `Map <WebElement> a` are simply illegal expressions.
`String` and `Boolean` are not valid collections.
`Map` will have to be defined for 2 object types: the `key` and the `value`, something like `Map <WebElement,Integer> map` while in order to add an entry to such map `a` you will need to write something like this:

```java
Map <WebElement, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
WebElement a = drive.driver.findElement(By.xpath("somelocator"));
map.put(a,1);
```